# Class doesn't accepts mocked dependencies when running phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel, laravel-4, mockery

I'm mocking two dependencies in my test which I pass to the class constructor of the class AlertsMessageBag. But php throws errors that I'm passing the wrong depedencies (Mockery\Mock). This happens when I run phpunit.

The error:

> 1) AlertsMessageBagTest::testAddByLevel
>   Argument 1 passed to Prologue\Alerts\AlertsMessageBag::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Session\Store, instance of Mockery\Mock given, called in /Users/Gebruiker/Sites/tests/workbench/workbench/prologue/alerts/tests/AlertsMessageBagTest.php on line 18 and defined in /Users/Gebruiker/Sites/tests/workbench/workbench/prologue/alerts/src/Prologue/Alerts/AlertsMessageBag.php:31 /Users/Gebruiker/Sites/tests/workbench/workbench/prologue/alerts/tests/AlertsMessageBagTest.php:18

My Test:

```
<?php

use Mockery as m;
use Prologue\Alerts\AlertsMessageBag;

class AlertsMessageBagTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function tearDown()
    {
        m::close();
    }

    public function testAddByLevel()
    {
        $session = m::mock('Illuminate\Session\Store');
        $config = m::mock('Illuminate\Config\Repository');

        $container = new AlertsMessageBag($session, $config);

        $container->error('foo');

        $messages = $container->get('error');

        $this->assertEquals(array('foo'), $messages);
    }

}
```

The AlertsMessageBag class:

```
<?php namespace Prologue\Alerts;

use BadMethodCallException;
use Illuminate\Session\Store;
use Illuminate\Config\Repository;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;

class AlertsMessageBag extends MessageBag {

    /**
     * Illuminate's Session Store.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Session\Store
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * Illuminate's Config Repository.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Config\Repository
     */
    protected $config;

    /**
     * Initialize the AlertMessageBag class.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Session\Store  $session
     * @param  array  $messages
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Store $session, Repository $config, array $messages = array())
    {
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->session = $session;

        // If there are already messages stored in the current
        // session, merge them with the provided messages.
        if ($session->has($this->getSessionKey()))
        {
            $messages = array_merge_recursive(
                $session->get($this->getSessionKey()),
                $messages
            );
        }

        parent::__construct($messages);
    }

    /**
     * Store the messages in the current session.
     *
     * @return \Prologue\Alert\AlertMessageBag
     */
    public function flash()
    {
        $this->session->flash($this->getSessionKey(), $this->messages);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the alert levels from the config.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getLevels()
    {
        return $this->config->get('alerts::levels');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the session key from the config.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getSessionKey()
    {
        return $this->config->get('alerts::session_key');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Illuminate Session Store.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Session\Store
     */
    public function getSession()
    {
        return $this->session;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Illuminate Config Repository.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Config\Repository
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return $this->config;
    }

    /**
     * Dynamically handle alert additions.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @return mixed
     * @throws BadMethodCallException
     */
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        // Check if the method is in the allowed alert levels array.
        if (in_array($method, $this->getLevels()))
        {
            return $this->add($method, $parameters[0]);
        }

        throw new BadMethodCallException("Method [$method] does not exist.");
    }

}
```

I just can't get why this is happening. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's some weird behaviour. Try calling `m::close()` before creating the mocks to make 100% sure no other tests are influencing the mockery container. Also try `var_dump($session instanceof \Illuminate\Session\Store)`, this should print true. Btw. if you chain directly after `m::mock()` using fluent interface you have to call `getMock()` to return the mock, but looks like you are not doing that in your code.

Comment: Hey Bram, thanks for helping out! Using `m::close()` before creating the mocks didn't work. This is the only test btw, there aren't any other tests. Trying the instanceof returns `Ebool(false)`.

Comment: Do you have laravel framework autoloading correctly setup in your test bootstrap? Mockery will not throw exception if class cannot be found. `$session = m::mock('Illuminate\Session\Sto');` will give you the same error if think. You could try `class_exists('Illuminate\Session\Store');` to make sure it can be found correctly.

Comment: Indeed, it can't find the classes. Could this be because it's a package I'm developing in the workbench? I never had any problems running unit tests before. When I go look at the `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` file in my workbench package then the array with classmaps is empty. I think this might be the problem.

Comment: I've never developed in Laravel 4 before. But if you installed it via composer the `Illuminate` namespace should be in your `vender/composer/autoload_namespaces.php`. the `autoload_classmap.php` will only de filled if you run `composer dump-autoload --optimize`. Now you have to make sure your bootstrap.php for phpunit is including the `vendor/autoload.php` file and you are using the right bootstrap file `phpunit --bootstrap=/patch/to/bootstrap.php`

Comment: I've now pulled the package out of the workbench and into a separate directory. I've installed the dependencies and they're now listed in the `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` file. I've definitely loaded in the correct bootstrap file when running phpunit. But I'm still getting the same error and doing `class_exists('Illuminate\Session\Store')` still returns `false`.

Comment: What happens if you try to instanciate a real instance of `Illuminate\Session\Store`?

Comment: Bram, thank you. I finally found out what the problem was. Pretty embarrassing. Turns out I forgot to require `illuminate/session` in the `composer.json` file. So the package worked as long as you installed it in a laravel project because `illuminate/session` is always installed then.
Thanks for all the help and sorry!

Comment: :-D. Part of our job. In the end it's always something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to require `illuminate/session` in my `composer.json` file. Quite embarrassing.